# Azure timed function not firing at correct interval

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a timed function in Azure that is not firing at the interval I've specific. Here is the trigger config:

[image: Trigger Config]

I'm expecting this to fire every 12 hours, but I've been getting strange behavior that seems out of sync with the system. This morning it started to fire every 30 mins. I had it configured incorrectly before and it was firing every hour but, as per the logs, it seems to be working as expected. And yet, I'm still getting the result of the function firing every 30 minutes sometimes.

[image: Logs]

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening.

Comment: How is the timer being sourced in code? Did someone perhaps override it with an app setting? Has there been a recent deployment of the backing code?

Comment: I found the reason, it had nothing to do with the timed function. I had a similar function in another part of the system that was firing every half an hour. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

The issue had nothing to do with the timed function - that is working as expected. There was a similar task being carried out in another part of the system.